# What does this mean about faces detection by using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

I'm trying to figure out the code about face detection. Here is the code that I can not understand:

```
MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                    new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
```

I'm wondering what does "faces" means and why have to turn it into Array by "faces.toArray"?
Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like detectMultiScale detects multiple face matches in the input image mGray. I'm not too sure the details of the MatOfRect class, but I think you have to call it's toArray() method to obtain the detected faces as an array of rectangles (each rectangle is a detected face). The conversion to array is probably for easier iteration over the matches.

Comment: I agree with @Stralo

Answer (score 0):

Haar cascade detector detects  "face" from the mgray(image) and stores it in faces(MatofRect), MatofRect hold 4 points namely(x,y,widht,height). These four points can be used to draw the rectangle around the detected "face".There can be more than one possible matches so it stored in array of Rect.